# Maximizing the area between a function and its linear approximation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry

Let $f: [a, b] \to [0, 1]$ be a monotonously increasing function and $y_f: [a, b] \to \Bbb R,\,\,x \mapsto \alpha x + \beta$ the corresponding linear approximation with constants $\alpha$, $\beta \in \Bbb R$. Hereby, the coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are determined by minimizing

\begin{align}
\int_a^b (f(x) - y_f(x))^2 dx.
\end{align}

I derived the values of the constants. They are of the form

\begin{align}
\alpha = \alpha_1 \int_a^b f(x) dx + \alpha_2 \int_a^b x f(x)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\beta = \beta_1 \int_a^b f(x) dx + \beta_2 \int_a^b x f(x),
\end{align}

with $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ depending only on $a$ and $b$.

The area enclosed by $f$ and $y_f$ is given by

\begin{align}
A(f) = \int_a^b |f(x) - y_f(x)|dx.
\end{align}

**My question:**

How to prove that it holds for the maximum value of the area

$\max(\{A(f), f: [a, b] \to [0, 1], \,\,f\,\,\text{monotonously increasing}\}) = \frac{1}{4}(b - a)$?

This is the value of $A(f)$ for the function $f(x) = \theta(x - (\frac{1}{2} (b - a) + a))$ which I assume to give the maximum value of $A(f)$. In other words, I'm looking for the function that has the largest deviation from its linear approximation.

Comment: Interesting problem.  I think I can show that the max is attained when $f$ is piece-wise constant, with at most 4 pieces, and agree with your conjecture.  (Assuming  your $\theta$ is the Heaviside functon.)

Comment: @kimchilover May I ask how you'd show that the max is attained when $f$ is piece-wise constant? Sounds interesting. I'd be very curious about that.

Comment: I have edited my answer extensively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since modifications of $f$ on sets of measure zero  don't change $A(f)$,
without loss of generality one can restrict to right-continuous $f$.   Such $f$ can be thought of as cumulative distribution functions of non-negative measures of total mass $\le1$ (that is, "sub-probability" measures) on $[a,b]$. Call this set of measures and/or corresponding cdfs $C$.  The set $C$ is compact in the weak topology, the function $C:f\mapsto A(f)$ is continuous in the weak topology on $C$,  so $A$ attains it maximum on $C$.  And $C$ is convex: it is the convex hull of the probability measures on $[a,b]$ and the zero measure on $[a,b]$; its extreme points correspond to the unit point masses in $[a,b]$ and the zero measure, that is, the functions $\mathbb 1_{[h,b]}$ for $h\in[a,b]$ and the zero function $\mathbb 1_\phi$.

But $A$ is also convex on $C$.
This follows because the map $f\mapsto f-y_f$ is linear (because the map $f\mapsto (\int_a^b f(x)dx,\int_a^b xf(x)dx)$ is linear), and because the map $g\mapsto \int_a^b|g(x)|dx=\|g\|_1$ is convex.  Since $A(f)=\|f-y_f\|_1$ is a convex function composed with a linear function of $f$, it is convex, too.

Since  $A$ is  convex and continuous on $C$  it attains its maximum at an extreme point of $C$, that is, at a function $f=\mathbb 1_{[h,b]}$ for some $h\in[a,b]$.  (Or the zero function $\mathbb 1_\phi$, which is an extreme point of  $C$ but has $A(\mathbb 1_\phi)=0$.)

To finish the job  a side argument should show which value(s) of $h$ maximizes this, but I don't have that yet.  Preliminary numerical experiments show that values of $h$ close to $.25$ and $.75$ are better than $h=1/2$.
In particular, when $[a,b]=[0,1]$, these values come up:  $A(\mathbb 1_{[.5,1]})\approx 0.208333332$ and $A(\mathbb 1_{0.7657,1]})\approx0.25149765$.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your proof. It's intriguing that values of $h \ne 0.5$ seem to give the maximum. I'd be curious whether one could determine the exact values of $h$ that give the maximum.

Comment: Intriguing indeed.  There are 3 cases, separated by the value of $h=1/3$ or $2/3$ , where the graph of $y_f$ crosses the $f=0$ part of the graph of $f$, or the $f=1$ part of the graph, or crosses both parts.  In each of these 3 ranges $A$ is a different rational function of $h$.  Calculus gives, in the one case I tried seriously, a degree $4$ polynomial solved by $h$.

Comment: Mathematica gives me the following closed form:
$$A(\mathbb 1_{[h,1]}) = \begin{cases}
 \cfrac{h \left(6 h^2-9 h+4\right)^2}{6 (1-h)} & h< \frac13 \\
 \cfrac{36 h^6-108 h^5+138 h^4-96 h^3+38 h^2-8 h+1}{6h(1-h)} & \frac13\leq h\leq\frac23 \\
 \cfrac{(1-h) \left(6 h^2-3 h+1\right)^2}{6 h} & h> \frac23.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Rahul  Thanks!  This seems to agree with what my program computes. The graph of this looks like a smooth inverted W, with 2 symmetrically disposed local maxima.